# How to extract number value from cell based on range

Tags: google-sheets, return-value, google-sheets-formula

I need to extract from list of calls with many extensions in one cell (see pic 1), the idea is to extract only values between 700 and 720 from each cell, I was trying to use regextract formula, but probably made mistakes. thank you for your time, waiting for response. (working platform - google sheets)

[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, as well as the formula attempt you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 followed by 0-1 followed by 0-9 : or 720

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"7[0-1][0-9]|720")
```

This would also accept 7100 etc. but is a starting point.

```
=regexextract(A2,"\D(7[0-1][0-9]|720)\D")
```

is more selective.

Comment: Thank you very much